# How many hadiths are in کتب الاربعه ? (Main Shia Books)

Tags: hadith, shiism, books

On the whole, **کتب الاربعه**  or **Kotob-al-Arba’ah (four books)** are deemed as the name of four Shiite books which is remarked as the most authentic book(s) of Shia. (Even these can be investigated as an authentic source in order to referring to, too) which consist of:

> 1. الکافى
> 2. من لا یحضره الفقیه
> 3. تهذیب الاحکام
> 4. الإستبصار فیما اختلف من الأخبار

I was wondering if there is any statistics about their numbers separately and totally. (About the number of hadiths)

Answer (score 2):

As salamu Alaikum

I found this from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Four_Books),

```
    Book                     - No of Hadith
    Kitab al-Kafi            - 16,199  
    Man la yahduruhu al-Faqi - 9,044  
    Tahdhib al-Ahkam         - 13,590  
    Al-Istibsar              - 5,511
```