# What is the difference between sunni hadith and other hadith?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

I recently saw that Musnad Ahmad contains 70% sunni hadith, what does it mean?

What is a sunni hadith? What is its specialty?

Comment: In Islam there are two mainstreams Sunni's and Shi'a beside other less known sects like Ibadi's all of them have their sources, in cases they have common sources and others different ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sassir said in his comment all Muslim sects have their own sources (they only have a consensus about the qur'an itself).

So when I say sunni hadith I mean hadith compilations which are wide spread and known or used by [sunni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunni_Islam) scholars and references starting with the two Sahih books of imam al-Bukhari and Muslim. See for example [Are there commentaries of Hadith collections outside the 7 most known books?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46014/are-there-commentaries-of-hadith-collections-outside-the-7-most-known-books) and [Is Musnad Ahmed a book of Sahih Ahaadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25875/is-musnad-ahmed-a-book-of-sahih-ahaadith) where some major works are mentioned.

On the other hand shi'a hadith sources are mentioned in
[How many hadiths are in کتب الاربعه ? (Main Shia Books)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28490/how-many-hadiths-are-in-%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%87-main-shia-books).
Maybe also relevant is [What theological and historical factors distinguish Ibadi Islam from either Shia or Sunni schools?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17755/what-theological-and-historical-factors-distinguish-ibadi-islam-from-either-shia/)